# What does [] mean in python docs?

Tags: python, zip

maybe this question is a little basic, but I'm reading the official docs in python:

```
ZipFile.extractall([path[, members[, pwd]]])
```

But I don't understand what the [] means?

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`[]` means that these are *optional* arguments that can be supplied to the function. The documentation will mention default values used otherwise.

Simple example using [open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open):

```
open(name[, mode[, buffering]])
```

The filename is *required*, but mode and buffering are *optional*. The default mode for opening a file is read, so `open(filename, 'r')` is equivalent to `open(filename)`. For `buffering` it states:  "If omitted, the system default is used"

Comment: @pawn thanks for the link, that's close to what I have been searching for. While this BNF like notation is similar to documentation conventions, I was trying to find a link (unsuccessfully) that showed conventions used for documentation. I have these in print, but couldn't find it online to include in my answer.